# How to monitor vcpu registers with kvm_sync_regs in kvm_run?

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, virtualization, kvm, vcpu

I would like to loop (;;) over the kvm_run structure during a guest execution, in order to monitor the vcpu registers. While reading the documentation, I saw that using the get_regs/set_regs were inefficient for that purpose. So I read about kvm_sync registers.
**But it is unclear to me whether we can read the registers while the guest is running, or the kvm_run struct is only updated at each VM_EXIT.**.

Here is a documentation about it : [Documentation on sync registers](https://docs.kernel.org/virt/kvm/api.html#kvm-cap-sync-regs). My goal is to monitor the vCPUs registers while running not only after a VM_EXIT.